# How do I count only unique values with groupby using pandas/python?

Tags: python, pandas

What can I do to this pandas dataframe to get it to count only the unique/distinct values of "Unique_Id"? Everything I have tried gives me unique values of community instead, or throws an error.

```
df.groupby("Community")["Unique_Id"].count().sort_values(ascending = False)
```

This is the output I get:

```
Comunidad_Autónoma
Cataluña                534415
Comunidad Valenciana    475411
Madrid                  415047
Islas Canarias          171939
País Vasco              168297
Navarra                  57045
La Rioja                 26057
Name: Unique_Id, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE]? May be you need `df['Unique_Id'].nunique()` ?

Comment: `df.groupby(["Community","Unique_Id"].count()`  if you are trying to get unique values unique_id by community groups. else `df['Unique_Id'].nunique()`

Comment: None of those worked. Thank you though!

Comment: can you provide the input (i.e., your ```df``)?

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to use [pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) before you call the groupby method. In the example below, Madrid has a duplicate Id:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Community = 'Cataluña,Madrid,Cataluña,Madrid,Cataluña,Madrid'.split(','),
    Unique_Id = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2],
))

df1 = df.drop_duplicates(
        ['Community','Unique_Id']
    ).groupby(
        'Community'
    )['Unique_Id'].count().sort_values(ascending = False)

print(df1)
print(f'\nTotal Unique_Ids Across All Communities: {sum(df1.values)}')
```

[Example Code In Python Tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20Community%20%3D%20'Catalu%C3%B1a,Madrid,Catalu%C3%B1a,Madrid,Catalu%C3%B1a,Madrid'.split%28','%29,%0A%20%20%20%20Unique_Id%20%3D%20%5B1,%202,%203,%204,%205,%202%5D,%0A%29%29%0A%0Adf1%20%3D%20df.drop_duplicates%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B'Community','Unique_Id'%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%29.groupby%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'Community'%0A%20%20%20%20%29%5B'Unique_Id'%5D.count%28%29.sort_values%28ascending%20%3D%20False%29%0A%0Aprint%28df1%29%0Aprint%28f'%5CnTotal%20Unique_Ids%20Across%20All%20Communities%3A%20%7Bsum%28df1.values%29%7D'%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=4&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)